# Connect Flow to 2 SP lists and link to list

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate

I have two Sharepoint Lists, Masterlist and Detailslist that contains lineitems. I use it for an Expenseapp.

So the item in Masterlist with ID 1, can have multiple Lineitems in Detailslist that alle have a corresponding ID 1. I would like to connect an approval Flow to Masterlist so that the manager only gets one approvalmail for several items in the Detailslist.

If an item with Id 1 is created in Masterlist, then send an approval mail to X containing a link to the corresponding items in Detailslist. This way the manager receives only one email but can still see all the items if he would like to, and approve it with one click.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Yes, you can fetch the list item from 2nd SharePoint list using "Send HTTP request to SharePoint" action by adding filter from list one and use it in send email action.

Comment: I edited my question because i was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get items action in the flow using Filter Query `ID eq "1"` to get corresponding  items  from Detailslist.

[image]